# Not full error message shown after importing RDF text snippet

Tags: graphdb, shacl

I am new to GraphDB. I am trying to use SHACL validation by pasting my shapes into the text field in the "import RDF text snippet" function. The problem I have is that if there is an error not the entire error message is shown. I can see "..." at the end of the error message that is shown but the details of what has gone wrong seem to be missing.

This is what I get:

> org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.shacl.GraphDBShaclSailValidationException:
> Failed SHACL validation
>
> ```
> @prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
>
> _:node1gh8je8tbx1779741  ...
> ```

The "..." at the end of the message show that there is more to this error message (and according to the SHACL validation I can expect more details to be shown in the error message).

I have tried it in both MS Edge and Chrome so I don't think it's a browser issue. There doesn't seem to be anything to expand the message. In case it makes a difference, I use Windows 10.

Comment: In case, it makes a difference. It's windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is intentionally cut off, because the violation reports tend to be too long. For the full message you can check GraphDB main log in /logs directory.

Comment: I saw in a video tutorial on using Shacl in GraphDB the full report in the import rdf snippet window. Anyway, I found the error logs. Thank you for your help!!